Similar triangles in quadrilateral with opposite right angles without using circles
Consider a convex quadrilateral $\square ABCD$ with the property that $\angle ABC=\angle CDA=90^\circ$. Drawing the line sedments $AC$ and $BD$ one obtains four triangles inside this quadrilateral. Let $P$ denote the point where $AC$ intersects $BD$. I wish to show that $\triangle ABP\sim\triangle CDP$ without using circles (in particular, I seek something using only very basic results on similar triangles). See the following figure for the setup.

I have not managed to make any substantial progress in this regard, however I did come up with a solution to the problem using circles (which I wish to avoid). For this I did the following:
As $\angle ABC+\angle CDA=180^\circ$ we can, by a theorem on inscribing quadrilaterals in circles, inscribe $\square ABCD$ in a circle. It follows now immediately by the inscribed angle theorem that $\angle BAC=\angle BDC$ and that $\angle ABD=\angle ACD$, and furthermore $\angle APB=\angle CPD$ by considering supplementary angles. As all three angles are the same it follows that the triangles are similar, showing the claim.

Now this proof seems to work to me, but I am specifically looking for a proof without using circles, only relying on more basic theorems on similar triangles. My geometry is very weak, and as a result I am unable to solve it myself.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Then prove by basic theorems that: 1) $MB = MD = MA = MC$; 2) $\angle ABD = \frac12 \angle AMD$ and $\angle ACD = \frac12 \angle AMD$ (e.g. by exterior angle and isosceles triangle theorems); and 3) with the known $\angle APB = \angle CPD$, $\triangle ABP \sim \triangle DCP$ (AAA).
